# $\sum E(|X_n - X|^r)$ converges implies almost sure convergence

Tags: probability

How do we show that if $\sum E(|X_n - X|^r) < \infty$ then $X_n {\to} X$ almost surely for $r > 0$?

I know that it's true for $\sum P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) < \infty$, but how do we extend this to account for the $r$-th mean?

Comment: Markov inequality might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum E(|X_{n}-X|^{r}) = E(\sum |X_{n}-X|^{r})$. So $\sum|X_{n}-X|^{r} < \infty$ a.s $\implies$ that $|X_{n}-X|^{r} \rightarrow 0$ a.s and therefore that $X_{n} \rightarrow X$ a.s